# How to prove $(A \cap B) \cap C \subseteq A \cap (B \cap C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

## My try:

Suppose $x \in \ (A \cap B) \cap C$. We know $x \in (A \cap B)$ and $x \in C$.
We can specialize and say that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ and $x \in C$.

From there I don't know how to synthetize the other set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(A \cap B) \cap C \subseteq A \cap (B \cap C)$$
$$x\in(A\cap B)\cap C$$
$$(x\in A\mbox{ and }x\in B)\mbox{ and }x\in C$$
$$x\in A\mbox{ and }(x\in B\mbox{ and }x\in C)$$
$$x\in A\cap(B\cap C)$$